# How to integration test prometheus metrics

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics

I have a golang server running that exposes metrics on a `/debug` endpoint. I want to test the metrics recorded when I hit an endpoint in my tests.

How do I capture the actual metrics recorded by my server and use them in my integration test? I saw lots of code examples on Github but they were all unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response body of an HTTP GET request against the metrics endpoint, in your case `/debug`, will return a plain-text representation of the metrics that looks like this:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the GC invocation durations.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0
```

The integration test can then parse the plain-text representation of the metrics to assert the desired value of the metric.

Comment: thanks I thought I might have to use the testutil package in `client_golang`